# Simple C Code going into Infinite Loop. Why?

Tags: c, loops, calculator, infinite, accumulator

Basically I am writing a simple command line calculator that implements an accumulator. I feel like this code is logically structured correct and I don't understand why it freezes for about 3 seconds before going into an infinite loop of print statements. Any help is appreciated.

```
void mycalc() {
  printf("Begin Calculations\n\n");
  printf("Initialize your Accumulator with data of the form \"number\" \"S\" which\
  sets the Accumulator to the value of your number\n");

  /* Initialize Variables */
  float accumulator, num;
  char op;

  /* Ask for input */
  scanf("%f %c\n", &num, &op);
  while (op != 'E') {
    if(op == 'S' || op == 's'){
      accumulator = num;
      printf("Value in the Accumulator = %f\n", accumulator);
    } else if(op == '+'){
      accumulator = accumulator + num;
      printf("Value in the Accumulator = %f\n", accumulator);
    } else if(op == '*'){
     accumulator = accumulator * num;
      printf("Value in the Accumulator = %f\n", accumulator);
    } else if(op == '/'){
      if (num == 0) {
          printf("Can not divide by 0.\n");
      } else {
          accumulator = accumulator / num;
          printf("Value in the Accumulator = %f\n", accumulator);
      }
    } else if(op == '-'){
      accumulator = accumulator - num;
      printf("Value in the Accumulator = %f\n", accumulator);
    } else if(op == 'E' || op == 'e'){
      printf("Value in the Accumulator = %f\n", accumulator);
      break;
    } else {
      printf("Unknown operator. \n");
    }
    scanf("%f %c\n", &num, &op);
  }
}
```

Would it be better to use the while(1) technique instead? Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'd try commenting out all the code in the `while` loop except for the `scanf` at the bottom. Then, above that `scanf`, print out the value of `op`. Does the error still occur? If so, something in the loop is the culprit; otherwise, something above it (or in the loop condition) is.

Comment: Yep, it still infinite loops while printing OP. Guess I need to change the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code does not handle bad input well.

In two places `scanf("%f %c\n", &num, &op)` has trouble with if non-numeric input is entered.  The `scanf()` fails, so `num` and `op` retain their old values.  The operation based on `op` occurs again and the next `scanf()` tries again with the *same* data.

The `"%f %c\n"` in 2 places is misleading in that the `\n` performs differently than OP expectations.  Change to

```
scanf("%f %c", &num, &op);
```

Instead of using `scanf()`, recommend using

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) == NULL) {
  exit(-1); // handle EOF or error
}
if (sscanf(buf, "%f %c", &num, &op) != 2) {
  exit(-1); // syntax error.
}
```

---

Alternatively one could use the following.  Bad input will eventually get consumed but not so readily.

```
if (2 != scanf(" %c %f", &op, &num)) {
  ; // syntax error.
}
```

---

Other issues: accumulator is not initialized

```
float accumulator = 0.0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and help. I have the code working perfectly now.

Quick question though, why is the \n in the scanf misleading?

Comment: A `\n` in a `scanf("%f %c\n")` mean to consume _all_ the next whitespace.  `scanf("%f %c ")` would do the same thing.  So typing in "123 S" then <enter> does not complete the input because additional whitespace could follow.  The <enter> did  not finish the input.  Ones needs to keep typing until a non-white space is entered.  Since `stdin` is buffered, it also means you have to enter another <enter>.  Then the first `scanf()` is done after you have enter 2 lines of input.  On your next `scanf()` the queued 2nd line of input is all ready entered, but you need a non-white space 3rd line.  Ugh.